# Posssible to go back in a for-loop after it's done?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make an anagram program and my program is semi working. Sometimes it gives me the strings that I want which are the first and the last two strings. But sometimes it doesn't print anything.

I thought I could fix that problem by putting the second `for` loop inside a function so that if the last `if` statements don't get called, I could run the whole second loop again. But when I do that, it prints a bunch of stuff and then the program reaches the print limit and crashes. I then tried the put the second for loop inside a `while` loop but when I do that the program doesn't even run.

```
text = "texxtttt"
text_list = ["tettxtxt", "ttexxtte", "texxtexxxt", "tttttxxe", "txextttt"]

input_unique_letters = "".join(set(text))

for i in range(len(input_unique_letters)):
    input_letter = input_unique_letters[i:i+1]
    input_letter_n = text.count(input_letter)

for i in range(len(text_list)):
    list_unique_letters = "".join(set(text_list[i]))

    list_word = text_list[i]
    list_letter = list_word[i:i+1]
    list_letter_n = list_word.count(list_letter)

    if len(text) == len(list_word):
        if input_letter == list_letter and input_letter_n == list_letter_n:
            print(list_word)
```

Heres the code that reaches the printing limit:

```
text = "texxtttt"
text_list = ["tettxtxt", "ttexxtte", "texxtexxxt", "tttttxxe", "txextttt"]

input_unique_letters = "".join(set(text))

for i in range(len(input_unique_letters)):
    input_letter = input_unique_letters[i:i+1]
    input_letter_n = text.count(input_letter)

def coroutine():
    for i in range(len(text_list)):
        list_unique_letters = "".join(set(text_list[i]))

        list_word = text_list[i]
        list_letter = list_word[i:i+1]
        list_letter_n = list_word.count(list_letter)

        if len(text) == len(list_word):
            if input_letter == list_letter and input_letter_n == list_letter_n:
                print(list_word)

        else:
            coroutine()

coroutine()
```

Comment: what is the input and expected output? please edit your question and include what you want and what the output of your program is

Comment: If you want to repeat anything you should likely use reusable code such as a class or function. You could assign a variable to the first function and then use it in the second function alternatively you can make a function recursive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some comments on your code:

- No, you can't "go back in a for loop". You can use a while loop and increment or decrement the index, if you really need to. Here that does not seem necessary.
- You rarely need to use `for i in range(len(text_list)):`. Consider using `for letter in text_list:` or, if you really need the index as well, `for i, letter in enumerate(text_list):`
- `list_letter = list_word[i:i+1]` seems strange. Why not just `list_letter = list_word[i]`?
- Why do you turn the set of letters into a string? We only iterate through the letters, and order does not matter anymore.
- The variable `input_letter_n` will just equal the last value encountered. You're not storing the previous values anywhere.

Here's some code that is based on yours, but more Pythonic:

```
def anagram(): 
    text = "texxtttt"  
    text_list = ["tettxtxt", "ttexxtte", "texxtexxxt", "tttttxxe", "txextttt"] 
    input_unique_letters = set(text) 
    count_dict = {letter: text.count(letter) for letter in input_unique_letters} 
    for list_word in text_list: 
        word_unique_letters = set(list_word) 
        for letter in word_unique_letters: 
            if letter in input_unique_letters: 
                if list_word.count(letter) == count_dict[letter]: 
                    print(list_word) 
                    break
```

A few crucial changes:

- I do not use a string, but just work directly with sets.
- To keep track of the counts, I use a dictionary, mapping letters to counts.
- The `break` statement makes it so that each word gets printed at most once. If that happens, we leave the `for letter in word_unique_letters` loop.

Comment: No worries. We all were beginners once. I still learn new things about Python all the time, and I've been using it as my main language for over a decade.